# Insert pair as map value

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

```
typedef pair<unsigned char, unsigned char> pair_k;
map<unsigned char, pair_k> mapping;
```

Which will be used this way:

```
mapping[100] = make_pair(10,10);
```

Question is:

1. Is this allowed? Syntaxically, it feels alright.
2. Would this be access as an array as oppose to a map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That looks ok to me.  But note that this is *not* array access; it just looks like it because `std::map` overloads `operator[]`.  If you do `mapping.size()` afterwards, you will find that it will be `1`.

Answer (score 7):

The std::map `operator[]` returns a reference to the map element identified by 100 (key), which is then overwritten by the pair returned by std::make_pair(10,10).

I would suggest:

```
map.insert( std::make_pair( 100, std::make_pair(10,10) ) );
```

The insert call has the advantage of accessing the map only once.

Comment: This is certainly a useful tip, but it doesn't seem to answer the questions asked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, ill might just use thins instead of the one I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfectly valid C++ code according to the standard hence it is allowed. It accesses the map as as a map only i.e. the *value* 100 is mapped to the pair `(10,10)`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try it?

```
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <map>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    using std::map;
    using std::pair;
    using std::make_pair;

    typedef pair<unsigned char, unsigned char> pair_k;
    map<unsigned char, pair_k> mapping;

    mapping[100] = make_pair(10,10);

    assert(1 == mapping.size());
    assert(10 == mapping[100].first);
    assert(10 == mapping[100].second);
    assert(false);
    return 0;
}
$ g++ test.cpp -o test
$ ./test 
Assertion failed: (false), function main, file test.cpp, line 18.
Abort trap
bash-3.2$
```

1. It is certainly allowed and behaves as expected.
2. This is accessing the `*map*` via its [subscript `operator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/). It is not array access.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use C++11 uniform initializer as below

```
map.insert({100, {10, 10}});
```